# How can i loop function variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, numpy

This is my current code:

```
import numpy as np

vec0 = [1, 2, 3]
vec1 = [2, 3, 4]
vec2 = [3, 4, 5]
vec3 = [4, 5, 6]

for k in range(0, 4):
    globals()['mean%s' % k] = np.mean('vec'+str(k))
```

I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

---

I want to this result.

```
mean0 = np.mean(vec0)
mean1 = np.mean(vec1)
mean2 = np.mean(vec2)
mean3 = np.mean(vec3)
```

Comment: 1) You don't want to be creating dynamically named variables and 2) if you use numpy properly, you can make that a single 2D array and take the mean over the row axis...

Comment: This is actually an anti-pattern, Usually it is bad design to call variables by name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
vecs = [vec0, vec1, vec2, vec3]
```

and then :

```
globals()['mean%s' % k] = np.mean(vecs[k])
```

Although, you should avoid this approach and maintain a `2D Array` instead, which will be easier for computing means using the row-axis.

What I mean is, instead of this:

```
vec0 = [1, 2, 3]
vec1 = [2, 3, 4]
vec2 = [3, 4, 5]
vec3 = [4, 5, 6]
```

you can have something like this :

```
vecs = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]])
```

and then you can simply calculate the means like this:

```
meansArray = vecs.mean(axis=1)
```

which will have your `mean0, mean1, mean2, mean3` at the respective indices.

Answer (score 1):

It is an anti-pattern to call variables *by name*. In case you need to perform a task on multiple objects, you can construct a collection (a tuple, a list, etc.) of these objects. For instance:

```
all_vecs = [vec0, vec1, vec2, vec3]
```

Furthermore you can now easily process the averages in *bulk* with numpy by specifying an `axis` parameter:

```
all_means = np.mean(all_vecs,axis=1)
```

then:

```
>>> all_means
array([ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by changing:

```
globals()['mean%s' % k] = np.mean('vec'+str(k))
```

to

```
globals()['mean%s' % k] = np.mean(globals()['vec%s' % k])
```

But I highly recommend using a vector instead:

```
all_vec = [vec0, vec1, vec2, vec3]
```